# How to Configure for Intranet Only Access? Apache, Ubuntu Server 18.04, Hyper-V VM

Tags: server, apache2, virtualization, hyper-v, intranet

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 Server running Apache on a Hyper-V VM. Right now as it's set up it can be accessed from anywhere on the web, how do I restrict access to the internal network only for setting up a intranet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out on my own!

```
sudo ufw default deny
sudo ufw allow from (local ip address, use 0 as last #)/24
sudo ufw reload
```